# Using Java & Apache Nutch to scrape dynamic elements from a website

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I want to do scraping in Java, and apache nutch comes to be the first choice. I have to scrape dynamic elements from website like price and mileage of vehicle. I have done the setup and tried to execute nutch for the seed.txt url - https://www.andersondouglas.com. But all i can see in crawl/segments is a file which just contains URL name. I cant see/find the HTML content of the crawled webpage.
Can someone please help. How can i scrape the HTML content.

apache-nutch version 1.19

Comment: "apache-nutch version 1.9" -- you mean 1.19? - 1.9 would be a quite old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the steps to fetch a URL and to export the HTML of the fetched page:

0. Install Nutch and configure the agent name as described in the [Nutch tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial). Except for the agent name all other configuration settings are the default ones. The next steps are run in an empty directory. The command `nutch` stands for `...nutch_install_path/bin/nutch`.
1. place the URL into the seed file: `echo https://nutch.apache.org/ >seeds.txt`
2. inject the seed into the CrawlDb: `nutch inject crawldb seeds.txt`
3. generate a segment: `nutch generate crawldb/ segments/`
4. fetch the generated segment: `nutch fetch segments/20230310113604/` (the segment name is a time stamp, it needs to be adapted)
5. (optionally) parse the segment: `nutch parse segments/20230310113604/` (only required if metadata, outlinks or plain text are required)
6. get the record of the URL (it includes the HTML but also more information):

   ```
   $> nutch readseg -get segments/20230310113604/ https://nutch.apache.org/
   ...
   Content:
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en-us">

   <head>
     <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.92.2" />
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title> Apache Nutch™ </title>
     ...
   ```
7. (alternatively) dump the segment:

   ```
   nutch readseg -dump segments/20230310113604/ segdump -recode
   ```

   - the HTML text is written to `segdump/dump`
   - it's recoded to UTF-8
   - run `nutch readseg` to get the help for more command-line options

Answer (score 0):

The raw content of a page (HTML but could be also a binary format such as PDF) is stored in the segments in the subfolder "content". Note, that the content is only stored

- if the property `fetcher.store.content` is true (this is the default) and
- if fetching was successful (a trial to fetch the given URL resulted in a HTTP 403 Forbidden). Very likely the site is protected.

Comment: Could you list the steps of how to use apache nutch to open any URL - can be www.google.com and store the HTML content of it to a text file. The content stored is binary content, how to make it readable.

Comment: I always get the content/part-r-0000/data as empty. I dont know why the data is not coming in the data file in content folder. I have tried with many URLs(which are not blocked/forbidden) in seed.txt file.

Comment: I'll add another answer with the steps required to export the HTML content from a segment. But keep in mind: Nutch is clearly not meant as a 1:1 replacement of curl or wget. The data is stored in a binary format (Hadoop sequence files) and it takes a couple of steps to export it.

Comment: Hey, i tried to crawl website - https://www.dutchmillerchevy.com/.
But seems like it is giving 403 forbidden http status code. I added proxy, user-agent, plugin.inclues=protocol-httpclient, http.robots.agents=*.
Yet the "https" websites' content is not being scraped. What all changes to do in nutch-site.xml to scrape data from this mentioned url

Comment: I am able to fetch content data from http website like https://thefreedictionary.com/.
But not able to scrape content data from - https://www.dutchmillerchevy.com/ & https://www.andersondouglas.com/used-vehicles/?q=3gncjksb5kl218243.

Comment: Could I integrate selenium in nutch? If yes, how can that be done?

Comment: Selenium is already integrated into Nutch, see [protocol-selenium](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium). But maybe keep the questions separate: 1. how to read the raw HTML from Nutch segment files, 2. how circumvent bot-protection, 3. (the original question) how to extract elements of a web page (eg. the price). The [Nutch user mailing list](https://nutch.apache.org/community/mailing-lists/) may be the better place to discuss very specific use cases with a set of questions.